# Is this insulation asbestos?

Tags: insulation, asbestos

A home inspector found this single piece of insulation around a wooden beam near our furnace. The report says that it “appears to be an asbestos-like substance”, but he did not lab test it. I’ve been unable to find anything online that is asbestos-based and resembles this material. I may just order a test online, but I’m curious if anyone immediately recognizes this as something else.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the plethora of [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+is+this+asbestos&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1019US1019). The answer is almost always "it looks like ___, but you'll have to have it tested." I will say that of all the questions I've seen like this, this is one I'd be more concerned about, given its proximity to the chimney components.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nobody, but _nobody_ can tell if it's asbestos just by looking at it. The only way to know for sure is to get it tested. Also, unless you've been actively ripping it to shreds and breathing deeply the resulting dust cloud, you're most likely just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably asbestos, but who knows. It's impossible to guess just by looking. Just get it tested. It's $15 to send a sample to a lab and you will have a definitive answer. But either way, you can just get a P100 mask, get it wet, remove it, discard it.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered that thick paper-like stuff many many times when working in old houses. Typically it was used to wrap or line heating ductwork and wood framing used to form ductways. As a matter of fact, I used to have a big roll of it I found somewhere, and it was very useful for making temporary flame shields for the copper pipe soldering I did. The sensible thing to do would be just to wet it down, tear it off, and toss in garbage. Making a fuss over something like that is just foolish.